# How to programmatically add a UI to a widget based on a Qtvtkwidget?

Tags: qt, user-interface, widget

I am trying to write a program based of of this [example](http://dev.pointclouds.org/issues/342) i.e. a widget based on `QVTKWidget`, so that I can use the `PCL Visualizer` inside the widget, with no UI and the first step for me would be to add a simple UI a menubar with some simple options: close,save etc.

Unfortunately my experience with QT interfaces is with the Designer, I have though seen what `ui` files look like but I have seen no tutorials on how to add them to widgets, tutorials for adding them to main windows I've seen a few.

Do you know of a simple method to add a .ui file to a `QVTKWidget` or a widget in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create an application, or a widget in designer, then add a plain `QWidget` into the content, this `QWidget` you promote to type `QVTKWidget`, through the designer interface as described in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html). Then you can add all the other ui elements to the application and interact with the `QVTKWidget`

Comment: So if I'm understanding you correctly I create a new `QVTKWidget` in this manner then just copy over all of the code from that tutorial I linked to.I'll try to do this.